# JS : what is best way to search multi-dimensional array of unknown depth?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sql-server

I have a multi-dimensional array in Javascript as part of a d3 visualisation that parses SQL code. It follows the structure below. Beyond the initial level, it grows in a regular way, i.e. field names in position 0, alias names in position 1 and children at position 2:

```
var matrix2 = [];

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {

    matrix2[i]=[];
    matrix2[i][0] = 'tableName'+i;
    matrix2[i][1] = 'tableAlias'+i;
    matrix2[i][2] = [];//context
    matrix2[i][3] = [];//alias
    matrix2[i][4] = [];//field
}


matrix2[0][2][0] = "field8 + field9 as alias3";
matrix2[0][3][0] = [];//alias array
matrix2[0][3][0][0] = ["alias3"];
matrix2[0][4][0] = [];//field array
matrix2[0][4][0][0] = "field8";
matrix2[0][4][0][1] = "field9";


matrix2[3][2][0] = "field1 + field2 - field3 as alias1";
matrix2[3][3][0] = [];//alias array
matrix2[3][3][0][0] = ["alias1"];
matrix2[3][4][0] = [];//field array
matrix2[3][4][0][0] = "field1";
matrix2[3][4][0][1] = "field2";
matrix2[3][4][0][2] = "field3";

matrix2[3][2][1] = "field4 + field5 - field6 as alias2";
matrix2[3][3][1] = [];//alias array
matrix2[3][3][1][0] = ["alias2"];
matrix2[3][4][1] = [];//field array
matrix2[3][4][1][0] = "field4";
matrix2[3][4][1][1] = "field5";
matrix2[3][4][1][2] = "field6";
matrix2[3][4][1][3] = "field7";

matrix2[3][3][1][1] = [];//children of alias2
matrix2[3][3][1][1][0] = [];//first child
matrix2[3][3][1][1][0][0] = [];//array for fields
matrix2[3][3][1][1][0][0][0] = "child1";
matrix2[3][3][1][1][0][0][1] = "child1a";
matrix2[3][3][1][1][0][1] = ["chdAlias1"];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][0][2] = [];//grandkids
matrix2[3][3][1][1][1] = [];//second child
matrix2[3][3][1][1][1][0] = [];//array for fields
matrix2[3][3][1][1][1][0][0] = "child2";
matrix2[3][3][1][1][1][1] = ["chdAlias2"];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][1][2] = [];//grandkids
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2] = [];//third child
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][0] = [];//array for fields
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][0][0] = "child3";
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][1] = ["chdAlias3"];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2] = [];//grandkids

matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][0] = [];//children of child3
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][0][0] = [];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][0][0][0] = "grandchild1";
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][0][1] = ["grandchildAlias1"];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][0][2] = [];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][1] = [];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][1][0] = [];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][1][0][0] = "grandchild2";
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][1][1] = ["grandchildAlias2"];
matrix2[3][3][1][1][2][2][1][2] = [];
```

I am too invested in this project easily to change the data structure - the graphic works etc.

The test SQL is a complex query, with multiple layers. So a field called "Staff_lastname" may exist at the table level (tbl.staff_lastname as lastname), and then multiple times in later sections of the code based on the alias (lastname as lastname) or (concat(firstname,' ' ,lastname) as name).

When sorting the data, I need to place the field name at the deepest level in the matrix that I can. So if the field I need to place is"lastname" and I have lastname at level 0 and lastname at level 1, I would pick level 1 in preference (when dealing with a field at level 2).

I need to loop through my multi-dimensional array, not knowing how deep it goes at any stage, and mindful that the data structure changes from the initial structure and that there might be multiple matches.

So far I've been trying to use recursive arrays to do this. However the problem is I typically find a match at too early a level and miss deeper matches. By passing in a section of the array, I can narrow that down to kids and grandkids - but it seems impossible to begin checking grandkids and work backwards. I can in theory create an array of matches and loop through them later.

But now I wonder if I'm missing a trick and I could use array prototype filter or something similar, to create a temporary (flat) array, and search for a match without worrying about nested loops. Has anyone done this?

(I haven't posted my JS because it is thousands of rows and highly interconnected. Hopefully this query makes sense without it.)

Very grateful for any tips

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can replace the contents of your `for` with:  `matrix2[i] = [ 'tableName'+i, 'tableAlias'+i, [], [], []];`

Comment: can you please add a problem with solution, eg data you want to get within the already posted code?